# Link Error in "Attention! Some of your previous edits were rejected." message

Tags: bug, review, user-profiles

When you receive the following message:

[image: screenshot of the error message]

The hyperlinked page is https://superuser.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=suggestions

which did not seem to provide what was described: instead I changed "activity" to "activities" and the page shown seemed to work:

https://superuser.com/users/current?tab=activities&sort=suggestions

Perhaps the "activities" tab used to just be "activity"

Comment: It sounds like this should be at http://meta.stackexchange.com/ since its unlikely to be only a Superuser problem.

Comment: @Ramhound I would imagine so, however, I cannot verify and trigger on the other sites, so I will leave to mods/admins to migrate or investigate as needed